# SKSpriteNode creation causing framerate drop

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm having a very strange problem which I have reached a dead end with. I have found where the problem is happening through the profiler, but I have no clue why it is happening, and so I can't fix it.

First a little description of my problem. I am creating a game, and one of the main updates is the HUD update which occurs every frame. Part of updating the HUD is changing a string that displays the ammo, health, and current level of the character and these three lines of code are shown here:

```
self.clip.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu/%lu", (unsigned long)ammo, (unsigned long)maxAmmo];
self.levelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level %lu", (unsigned long)level];
self.lifeAmount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%lu", health, (unsigned long)maxHealth];
```

Ammo, maxAmmo, level, health, and maxHealth are all passed into this method via the character object. When my problem arises, theses are the lines that are taking up the most CPU and causing frame rate glitches.

Now this next section of code is brought up via a pause menu. It is extremely rough and therefore might look dumb, but it basically brings up a screen with a grid of SKSpriteNodes arranged in a grid which will eventually be slots for weapon inventory.

```
- (void)setUpInventory {

    CGFloat rowOffset = self.frame.size.width / kInventoryColumns / 2;
    CGFloat colOffset = self.frame.size.height / kInventoryRows / 2;
    NSInteger count = 0;

    for (int row = kInventoryRows - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
        for (int col = 0; col < kInventoryColumns; col++) {

            SKSpriteNode *inventoryThing;
            if (count < [self.player.inventory count]) {
                inventoryThing = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(rowOffset * 2 - 4, colOffset * 2 - 4)];
            } else {
                inventoryThing = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(rowOffset * 2 - 4, colOffset * 2 - 4)];
            }
            inventoryThing.position = CGPointMake(col * (self.frame.size.width / kInventoryColumns) + rowOffset, (self.frame.size.height / kInventoryRows) * row + colOffset);
            [self addChild:inventoryThing];
            [self.inventorySprites addObject:inventoryThing];
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

When the pause button is pressed, the game displays this scene, and then there is a return button that brings you back to the gameplay.

Here is the strange part: the first three lines of code cause no problems whatsoever when they update every frame during gameplay. The problem arises after I go to the inventory screen and then leave. From there, the first time one of the labels changes (for example, I shoot my gun and the clip reduces by 1 and so the HUD changes or I get hit and my health bar is changed) I get a vary large frame drop which makes the game unplayable.

I have no idea why this is happening and why it only happens after pulling up the inventory screen. I can fix the frame rate glitches by having the three lines execute on a background thread but this causes the HUD update to be delayed and so is not a viable option for me.

Any help is very much appreciated and I can give more details if needed.

EDIT: 
Here's a little more information. The gameplay part of the game is its own skscene. The pause button creates a new custom skscene (menuScene) and presents it. All this menu Scene does I'd call setUpInventory in in it with size. This menu is given a gameplay scene property which is set right before it is presented, so when the return button is pressed, the menu Scene simply presents its gameplay scene. Since the gameplay scene does not have a menu scene property, I'm assuming this will get rid of all the sprites created in the menu so that shouldnt be a problem, although I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough information in your question but here something to check.

You've only shown your `setUpInventory`, which in the inner loop you are creating new `SKSpriteNode`'s and setting their position before adding them to your (presumably) `SKScene`.

So, first point how many sprites are you creating? Too many and you'll have issues…

When the users dismisses the inventory what is happening to the existing inventory sprites?

As you've added them to your `SKScene` they will hang around until your either remove them from the scene `[SKAction removeFromParent]` or remove the `SKScene` they attached to.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I added a little more information to the question. I do get rid of the skscene they are attached too (i think) by displaying a separate scene and not holding a reference to the scene with all the sprite nodes. I have also tested this by overriding dealloc (which I checked is called when the return button is pressed) to delete all these sprite nodes, but it does not make a difference
If it helps at all, I don't think creating the nodes I'd necessarily the problem. During gameplay, there are up to a few hundred nodes on screen and in the menu there are about 30